# Collect data from two different tables

Tags: sql

Hey guys I'm currently collecting data from the table `zuordnung` but I want to collect data from the table `users` as well, in the same query.

Here is my current SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `ID_Zuordnung`, `Username`, `Hostname_alt`, `Datum_Ausgabe` FROM `zuordnung` WHERE `Status_Tausch` = 'OK' AND `Status_Altgeraet` = 'NOK' ORDER BY `Hostname_alt` ASC"
```

From the table `users` I want to select the columns `Emailadresse, Abteilung` the primary key is `Username`

How can I do this do I need `inner join` or `full join` or something other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the two tables like so:

```
SELECT 
  z.ID_Zuordnung, z.Hostname_alt, z.Datum_Ausgabe,
  u.Emailadresse, u.Abteilung, u.Username
FROM `zuordnung` z
INNER JOIN users u ON z.Username = u.Username
WHERE z.Status_Tausch    = 'OK' 
  AND z.Status_Altgeraet = 'NOK' 
ORDER BY z.`Hostname_alt
```

Comment: don't work tested it again in php my admin and got this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Emailadresse, u.Abteilung, u.Username
FROM `zuordnung` z
INNER JOIN users u O' at line 3  Can you fix this error?

Comment: @Alesfatalis - Can you please show me the full query you tried? It is a syntax error near `.Emailadresse` may be you forgot to alias `.Emailadresse`

Comment: i just copied youre syntax which you posted in to phpmyadmin

Comment: @Alesfatalis - Sorry it was a missing comma `,` after the first line. Sorry again. See my edit.